# Enable one handed mode in iPhone 6 simulator?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, ios-simulator

The iPhone 6 Plus has a "one handed mode" that Apple describes as "Keep everything within reach" on their [iPhone design](http://www.apple.com/iphone-6/design/) page.

The mode is enabled by double touching (but not pressing) the home button. When enabled the screen shrinks to roughly half its normal height.

Is there a way to enable this mode in simulator for testing how it looks and transitions?

I'm running Xcode 6 GM and have not been able to uncover anything. Worst case, can someone post the exact dimensions on device so it can be emulated via the resizable iPhone simulator?

---

Update: According to [John Gruber's review](http://daringfireball.net/2014/09/the_iphones_6), the feature is available on the iPhone 6 Plus **and** 6, and is not a "mode" so much as a momentary shortcut. Maybe since it only lasts for one tap it won't be important to do extensive testing. He shared a screenshot showing the corresponding size difference:

[image: Reachability compared between iPhone 6 and 6 Plus]

Comment: Filed a bug report as it appears this is still not in 6.0.1 Xcode: http://openradar.appspot.com/18347885

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simulator doesn't seem to have this capability, but it doesn't matter since it just moves your app's entire view down and uses the home screen background to fill the top. Devs don't need to do anything to their apps in regards to it.

Comment: Thanks, but it might be nice in case we want to make sure certain buttons that are near the half way point are in the tappable region (or not). Agree that it's not necessarily required as the bounds don't change as I initially believed. I'll accept if they close the enhancement request saying it is not planned.

Comment: Sorry, but Harrison is correct.  The iOS Simulator app does not have a way for developers to send the reachability event to the runtime.  If this is of interest to you, please file a radar at http://bugreport.apple.com